# 0x8004010F when downloading Exchange offline address book

Tags: exchange-2003, outlook-2007

Situation:

Single domain consisting of 3 DCs (2 x Windows 2008 R2 std, 1 x Windows 2003 R2 std) - each DC is a GC

Single exchange server (Exchange 2003 Std)

Clients, mainly Win XP, but some Win 7, Outlook 2007.

All systems fully patched.

Every hour, an item apepars in the 'Sync issues' folder in outlook. The contents of the message are as follows:

```
16:27:00 Synchronizer Version 12.0.6509
16:27:00 Synchronizing Mailbox 'Joe Bloggs'
16:27:00 Done 16:27:00 Microsoft Exchange offline address book
16:27:00    0X8004010F
```

This message can also be created on demand by clicking (in outlook) on Tools > Send/Receive > Download Address Book...

The address book isn't updating (I made some changes a few days ago, and they still haven't arrived).

This problem has been going on for some time, but it's been low priority, however I really need to allow users to see the updates in the GAL.

I've tried the solutions offered in [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/905813), but without success. Can anyone offer any suggestions that might fix or identify the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message is pretty generic, and can indicate one of a number of errors. There's a good blog article [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/dgoldman/archive/2008/10/01/understanding-why-error-code-0x8004010f-is-thrown-when-trying-to-download-an-oab.aspx) that lists a number of potential reasons and solutions.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a good resource. I'll start reading.