# User with Outlook receiving emails every hour regarding Microsoft Exchange offline address book 0X8004010F

Tags: outlook, exchange-2010, synchronization

About 6 months ago we upgraded our Exchange server from 2003 to 2010.
I have read [0x8004010F when downloading Exchange offline address book](https://serverfault.com/questions/95383/0x8004010f-when-downloading-exchange-offline-address-book) and found that this issue is the same as what I am having.

I have also read the [blog post](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dgoldman/after-installing-an-exchange-2007-or-exchange-2010-server-in-to-a-mixed-site-the-oab-generation-fails-with-error-9342-and-outlook-clients-fail-to-download-the-oab-with-error-0x8004010f) mentioned the above question.

The problem is that I cannot use this method because the 2003 Exchange server has been decommissioned (properly).

Is there another solution so that this sync error can stop occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that there was a problem from when we removed our old exchange server from the network.
The offline address book needed to be recreated.
it was done through powershell.
I dont know the exact commands but it stopped this error from happening to all users.
It wasnt actually outlook at all.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to deal with similar issues, which I have been able to resolve, but not definitively enough to give an exact solution.  You can start, however, by recreating the OST file.  Just close Outlook, delete or rename the OST file, and then open Outlook back up.  It will recreate the file.  You can also try to completely recreate the mail profile.  Finally, you can try to turn logging off (or on and then back off).  [Here](http://www.technipages.com/outlook-2007-enabledisable-logging.html) are some instructions for doing that.

If none of that works, try turning off cached mode and see if the error still occurs.  That's not a solution, but it might help to see if you should look more into Outlook or Exchange.

Comment: I have ahad a look a bit further and have discovered that the user is not the only person receiving the email. However this user was using folder view which shows sync issues and conflicts. It is actually happening across all users. With recreating the OST it happens when this user logs onto a new machine that they havent logged onto before. So this would be a new profile.